# How do I set a background colour for QTextBrowser?? (PyQt)

Tags: pyqt, pyqt4

I have created a QTextBrowser and I wanted to know how i would set the background colour of the whole widget. 
I have tried `QTextBrowser.setBackground(QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.blue, QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern))` with no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case I suggest you to use stylesheet:
If in QDesigner, right click on the control, click "Set Stylesheet" and write

`background-color: blue;`

If you want to do it by code, just use

`YourControlTextBrowser.setStyleSheet("background-color: blue;")`